# ElasticBeanstalk Public URL - How to manage it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have one questions that is bugging me for the last couple of days.
Currently I'm running ElasticBeanstalk nodejs env, with custom domain, certificate wired up, http to https redirection, everything runs smoothly. But Public elasticbeanstalk address (myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com) is still accessible and non ssl, I understand that it's amazon ownership of subdomain.

My main question is how or what should I do with ElasticBeanstalk public domain (myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com). Should I leave it as it is or maybe restrict somehow access to it? Reason why I'm thinking about it is that myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com is accessible and non ssl.

Comment: If you use ALB, just redirect it to your own domain. If not, you have to setup "manually" nginx/apache to do it.

Comment: @Marcin I do use ALB, hmm will try 301 to domain. TBH I do not see any cons of doing it? BTW I guess I would need only to add it on 443 because 80 is redirecting to 443.

Comment: You want to redirect EB default hostname on port 80 to your domain?

Comment: Well port 80 automatically goes to 443 but yes EB default hostname is non ssl because of cert domain validation, so I'm actually redirecting eb default hostname 443 to domain.